# Exception thrown within try catch

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a function to check whether an email entered is valid:

```
bool IsValidEmail(string email)
    {
        try
        {
            var addr = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email);
            return addr.Address == email;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Even though it's within a try/catch I still get an exception when an invalid email is entered stating:

> 'The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.'

I have used this function in other applications and it works fine. Not sure what's going on with it now.

Edit: Solution was my Exception settings, my VS was ignoring the try/catch

Comment: Isn't that what is supposed to happen? The code is throwing an exception in the try, and catch is catching it. Unless you mean something else? Also, did you debug it to see what value does `email` have? It's clearly an invalid email.

Comment: Have you ever checked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/validation

Comment: If the email is invalid it's supposed to return false. It's not making it to the catch as its throwing the exception inside of the try

Comment: Check the link above , change the way to validate email address .

Answer (score 0):

```
catch (Exception ex)
```

can't catch all the exceptions. Only managed ones.

You can use catch without type:

```
catch
{
    return false;
}
```

Not sure if it is a good point. You can't handle something like `Environment.FailFast` call inside a constructor of MailAddress

Anyway, it looks like your problem is not there.

Please, add a stack trace of your exception if you want more help.